# Performance/speed of quantized models

Tags: artificial-intelligence, quantization

I tried multiple LLMs with quantization and all of them seems to become min 10x slower than the non-quantized version of the respective model. Is this an expected behavior? Is there a benchmark/tracker which has this information?

Most of them takes roughly 120 secs to make the inference on any task (200 output tokens)

GPU - A100 40GB

Falcon 7B
Falcon 40B
LLaMA (multiple versions)

Quantization config used:

```
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, quantization_config=bnb_config, device_map={"":0}, trust_remote_code=True)
```

(Also posted in https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues/537)